# QueryFailedError: malformed array literal when I'm trying to insert json array in postgres using typeorm

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I need to save json object with other nested objects into my postgres db. The json I'm receiving from user's browser.

I'm using Postgres 11.5 on AWS RDS. On backend I'm using NodeJS (NestJS/TypeScript/TypeORM).

I tried to convert each item of array to string using JSON.stringigy() but anyway I'm receiving error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: QueryFailedError: malformed array literal: "[{"name":"Oviedo, Asturias, Spain"},{"name":"Oviedo, Asturias, Spain"}]"`

Array looks like this:

```
"waypoints": [
        {
            "name": "Oviedo, Asturias, Spain"
        },
        {
            "name": "Oviedo, Asturias, Spain"
        }
    ]
```

This is a field to store the array above

```js
@Column({ type: 'jsonb', array: true })
    waypoints: any[];
```

And I assign data like this:

```js
  event.waypoints = eventData.waypoints;

  // also I tried to do like this
  event.waypoints = JSON.stringify([{ text: 'Some text' }, { text: 'Some text 2' }]);
```

Right now I'm receiving error:

```
(node:12833) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: QueryFailedError: malformed array literal: "[{"name":"Oviedo, Asturias, Spain"},{"name":"Oviedo, Asturias, Spain"}]"
    at new QueryFailedError (/home/banha/Projects/train-time-server/node_modules/typeorm/error/QueryFailedError.js:11:28)
    at Query.callback (/home/banha/Projects/train-time-server/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.js:176:38)
    at Query.handleError (/home/banha/Projects/train-time-server/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:142:17)
    at Connection.connectedErrorMessageHandler (/home/banha/Projects/train-time-server/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:211:17)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:209:13)
    at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/banha/Projects/train-time-server/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:126:12)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:209:13)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:305:12)
(node:12833) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12833) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Without  JSON.stringify , because it will parse it to a string not an array  event.waypoints = [{ text: 'Some text' }, { text: 'Some text 2' }]

Comment: Without stringify I have the same problem

Comment: Try with JSON.parse event.waypoints = JSON.parse([{ text: 'Some text' }, { text: 'Some text 2' }]);

Comment: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: What's the data type of that field in postgres? PG thinks it's an array literal, so if your field is jsonb then it's probably not being enclosed in single quotes (in the insert statement) to make it a "string", which it should be for a json/jsonb field. If it's an array of json/b, then each item in the array needs to be enclosed in single quotes instead. I don't know what this entails from the typeorm perspective.

Comment: parsing JSON will lead to the error above - you can only try to parse strings, indeed ; )
I got it working without `array: true` defined

Comment: Yes, I deleted `array:true` and It started to work without parsing